# BlackBerry - How to properly handle a TAP/CLICK in a custom Manager

Tags: java, blackberry

I need to set up a click/tap event for a custom Manager.

The Manager contains a couple of elements, but I need that the whole
Manager respond to the event, so if the user taps/clicks any element
inside the Manager, the event handler should be called too.
What I have done is to attach a changeListener to a NullField that takes all width and height, but the fieldChanged method is never called

```
public class TestManager extends Manager{
    private BitmapField _icon;
    private LabelField _lblTitle;
    private NullField nullField;
    public TestManager(Bitmap pIcon){
        super(Manager.FOCUSABLE);
        _icon = new BitmapField(pIcon);
        _lblTitle = new LabelField("This is the title");
        nullField = new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE);
        add(_icon);
        add(_lblTitle);
        add(nullField);
            nullField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            doSomething();
        }
    });

    }

    public void doSomething(){
    System.out.println("do something!!");
}
    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
       graphics.setColor(Color.DELIMITER_COLOR);
       graphics.fillRect(0, 20, Display.getWidth(), 50);

       super.paint(graphics);
    }

    protected void paintBackground(Graphics arg0) {
       arg0.setColor(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
       arg0.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
       super.paint(arg0);
    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        setPositionChild(_icon, UIFactory.getBestX(10), UIFactory.getBestX(8));
        setPositionChild(_lblTitle, UIFactory.getBestX(60), _topMarginTitle!=0?UIFactory.getBestX(_topMarginTitle):UIFactory.getBestX(15));
        setPositionChild(nullField, 0, 0);
        layoutChild(_icon, width, UIFactory.getBestX(50));
        layoutChild(_lblTitle, width, UIFactory.getBestX(50));
        layoutChild(nullField, width, height);
        setExtent(width, height);
    }

      protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){ 
            invalidate();
            doSomething();
            return super.navigationClick(status, time);
        }

}
```

How should I make this whole Manager to respond a click/tap?

I'm using the API 5.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question was also asked in BB forums, and I have responded there:
[BlackBerry-How-to-properly-handle-a-TAP-CLICK-in-a-custom](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BlackBerry-How-to-properly-handle-a-TAP-CLICK-in-a-custom/td-p/2628501)

Further to this, here is a solution to the problem:

```
public class BaseTouchManager extends Manager {

    private FieldChangeListener _callBack;

    public BaseTouchManager(FieldChangeListener pCallBack) {
        super(0);
        _callBack = pCallBack;
        setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                _callBack.fieldChanged(field, context);
            }
        });

        add(new NullField(Field.FOCUSABLE));
    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(Display.getHeight()/2, 100);
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            fieldChangeNotify(1);
            return true;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        if(_callBack!=null){
            if(isFocus())
                graphics.setColor(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
            else
                graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.fillRect(this.getWidth() - 10, 
                    this.getHeight() - 10, 
                    10, 10);

        }
        super.paint(graphics);  
    }
}
```

The original poster actually suggested a different solution, review the BB forum post for more.

Comment: thanks Peter, you are a living legend for BB! When the company closes, they should send you a big fat compensatory check for your huge contribution to the corporation! Soon you will become another S.O legend too!

Comment: @Lucas - Thanks.  I am still working on BB being around.  I like the BB10 devices.